# Iterating through an array inside an object, console.log working but I can not get it to return react elements.

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, foreach, map-function

I'm trying to extract the "main" data from this array of objects. I'm still pretty new to this so any advice would be helpful.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CurrentLocation extends Component {
  loopThroughKeys(obj) {
    return obj.forEach(function(obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).map(function() {
        let main = obj.main;
        return Object.keys(main).map(function(key) {
          let type = key;
          let value = main[key];
          console.log(type, value);
          return (
            <li>
              <span key={key}>
                {type}:{value}
              </span>
            </li>
          );
        });
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    let weather = this.props.weather;
    console.log(this.props.weather);
    if (!weather.list) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="currentWeather">
        <h1>hi</h1>
        <div className="container">
          <ul className="card">{this.loopThroughKeys(weather.list)}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CurrentLocation;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CurrentLocation extends Component {
  loopThroughKeys(obj) {
    return obj.forEach(function(obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).map(function() {
        let main = obj.main;
        return Object.keys(main).map(function(key) {
          let type = key;
          let value = main[key];
          console.log(type, value);
          return (
            <li>
              <span key={key}>
                {type}:{value}
              </span>
            </li>
          );
        });
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    let weather = this.props.weather;
    console.log(this.props.weather);
    if (!weather.list) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="currentWeather">
        <h1>hi</h1>
        <div className="container">
          <ul className="card">{this.loopThroughKeys(weather.list)}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CurrentLocation;

var weather.list={
cod: "200",
message: 0.0082,
cnt: 40,
list: [
{
dt: 1485799200,
main: {
temp: 283.76,
temp_min: 283.76,
temp_max: 283.761,
pressure: 1017.24,
sea_level: 1026.83,
grnd_level: 1017.24,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 7.27,
deg: 15.0048
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-01-30 18:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485810000,
main: {
temp: 282.56,
temp_min: 282.56,
temp_max: 282.563,
pressure: 1020.06,
sea_level: 1029.63,
grnd_level: 1020.06,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 6.21,
deg: 31.5035
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-01-30 21:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485820800,
main: {
temp: 282.3,
temp_min: 282.296,
temp_max: 282.3,
pressure: 1022.71,
sea_level: 1032.27,
grnd_level: 1022.71,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 6.71,
deg: 51.0002
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-01-31 00:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485831600,
main: {
temp: 282.27,
temp_min: 282.265,
temp_max: 282.27,
pressure: 1023.68,
sea_level: 1033.16,
grnd_level: 1023.68,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 5.46,
deg: 65.5
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-01-31 03:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485842400,
main: {
temp: 282.656,
temp_min: 282.656,
temp_max: 282.656,
pressure: 1023.75,
sea_level: 1033.22,
grnd_level: 1023.75,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 4.11,
deg: 84.0055
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-01-31 06:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485853200,
main: {
temp: 282.783,
temp_min: 282.783,
temp_max: 282.783,
pressure: 1024.91,
sea_level: 1034.46,
grnd_level: 1024.91,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 3.6,
deg: 89.0062
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-01-31 09:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485864000,
main: {
temp: 283.335,
temp_min: 283.335,
temp_max: 283.335,
pressure: 1025.21,
sea_level: 1034.83,
grnd_level: 1025.21,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 803,
main: "Clouds",
description: "broken clouds",
icon: "04n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 68
},
wind: {
speed: 3.37,
deg: 115
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-01-31 12:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485874800,
main: {
temp: 284.657,
temp_min: 284.657,
temp_max: 284.657,
pressure: 1023.65,
sea_level: 1033.43,
grnd_level: 1023.65,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 802,
main: "Clouds",
description: "scattered clouds",
icon: "03n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 36
},
wind: {
speed: 3.32,
deg: 177.501
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-01-31 15:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485885600,
main: {
temp: 284.095,
temp_min: 284.095,
temp_max: 284.095,
pressure: 1022.05,
sea_level: 1031.79,
grnd_level: 1022.05,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "02n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 8
},
wind: {
speed: 4.26,
deg: 254.003
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-01-31 18:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485896400,
main: {
temp: 283.211,
temp_min: 283.211,
temp_max: 283.211,
pressure: 1021.33,
sea_level: 1031.06,
grnd_level: 1021.33,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 4.32,
deg: 271.5
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-01-31 21:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485907200,
main: {
temp: 284.179,
temp_min: 284.179,
temp_max: 284.179,
pressure: 1020.57,
sea_level: 1030.28,
grnd_level: 1020.57,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 801,
main: "Clouds",
description: "few clouds",
icon: "02d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 20
},
wind: {
speed: 10.16,
deg: 256.504
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-01 00:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485918000,
main: {
temp: 284.829,
temp_min: 284.829,
temp_max: 284.829,
pressure: 1017.39,
sea_level: 1027.23,
grnd_level: 1017.39,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "02d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 8
},
wind: {
speed: 13.76,
deg: 259.502
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-01 03:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485928800,
main: {
temp: 285.702,
temp_min: 285.702,
temp_max: 285.702,
pressure: 1014.64,
sea_level: 1024.23,
grnd_level: 1014.64,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 801,
main: "Clouds",
description: "few clouds",
icon: "02d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 12
},
wind: {
speed: 12.75,
deg: 264.001
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-01 06:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485939600,
main: {
temp: 285.494,
temp_min: 285.494,
temp_max: 285.494,
pressure: 1014.1,
sea_level: 1023.71,
grnd_level: 1014.1,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 12.33,
deg: 271.5
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-01 09:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485950400,
main: {
temp: 285.16,
temp_min: 285.16,
temp_max: 285.16,
pressure: 1014.54,
sea_level: 1024.27,
grnd_level: 1014.54,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 12.21,
deg: 278.504
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-01 12:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485961200,
main: {
temp: 284.161,
temp_min: 284.161,
temp_max: 284.161,
pressure: 1016.13,
sea_level: 1025.81,
grnd_level: 1016.13,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 12.21,
deg: 281
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-01 15:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485972000,
main: {
temp: 282.63,
temp_min: 282.63,
temp_max: 282.63,
pressure: 1017.33,
sea_level: 1027,
grnd_level: 1017.33,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 9.3,
deg: 297.001
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-01 18:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485982800,
main: {
temp: 281.856,
temp_min: 281.856,
temp_max: 281.856,
pressure: 1018.51,
sea_level: 1028.24,
grnd_level: 1018.51,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 8.91,
deg: 288
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-01 21:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1485993600,
main: {
temp: 281.978,
temp_min: 281.978,
temp_max: 281.978,
pressure: 1019.22,
sea_level: 1028.89,
grnd_level: 1019.22,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 9.15,
deg: 286.504
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-02 00:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486004400,
main: {
temp: 283.706,
temp_min: 283.706,
temp_max: 283.706,
pressure: 1017.36,
sea_level: 1026.99,
grnd_level: 1017.36,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 8.95,
deg: 288.003
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-02 03:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486015200,
main: {
temp: 285.125,
temp_min: 285.125,
temp_max: 285.125,
pressure: 1016.41,
sea_level: 1026.05,
grnd_level: 1016.41,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 7.56,
deg: 294.002
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-02 06:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486026000,
main: {
temp: 284.755,
temp_min: 284.755,
temp_max: 284.755,
pressure: 1018.18,
sea_level: 1027.75,
grnd_level: 1018.18,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 8.31,
deg: 290.504
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-02 09:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486036800,
main: {
temp: 283.765,
temp_min: 283.765,
temp_max: 283.765,
pressure: 1019.04,
sea_level: 1028.51,
grnd_level: 1019.04,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 8.87,
deg: 283.001
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-02 12:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486047600,
main: {
temp: 283.809,
temp_min: 283.809,
temp_max: 283.809,
pressure: 1018.6,
sea_level: 1028.26,
grnd_level: 1018.6,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 8.73,
deg: 281.001
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-02 15:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486058400,
main: {
temp: 283.788,
temp_min: 283.788,
temp_max: 283.788,
pressure: 1018.68,
sea_level: 1028.33,
grnd_level: 1018.68,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 7.8,
deg: 281.503
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-02 18:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486069200,
main: {
temp: 283.569,
temp_min: 283.569,
temp_max: 283.569,
pressure: 1019.28,
sea_level: 1028.92,
grnd_level: 1019.28,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 5.92,
deg: 284.002
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-02 21:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486080000,
main: {
temp: 284.11,
temp_min: 284.11,
temp_max: 284.11,
pressure: 1020.75,
sea_level: 1030.35,
grnd_level: 1020.75,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 1.83,
deg: 284.506
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-03 00:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486090800,
main: {
temp: 285.034,
temp_min: 285.034,
temp_max: 285.034,
pressure: 1020.08,
sea_level: 1029.7,
grnd_level: 1020.08,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 1.01,
deg: 172.002
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-03 03:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486101600,
main: {
temp: 286.158,
temp_min: 286.158,
temp_max: 286.158,
pressure: 1018.77,
sea_level: 1028.39,
grnd_level: 1018.77,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 0.71,
deg: 181.009
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-03 06:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486112400,
main: {
temp: 286.138,
temp_min: 286.138,
temp_max: 286.138,
pressure: 1019.17,
sea_level: 1028.73,
grnd_level: 1019.17,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 1.51,
deg: 85.0026
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-03 09:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486123200,
main: {
temp: 285.952,
temp_min: 285.952,
temp_max: 285.952,
pressure: 1019.74,
sea_level: 1029.36,
grnd_level: 1019.74,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 3.68,
deg: 76.5032
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-03 12:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486134000,
main: {
temp: 285.828,
temp_min: 285.828,
temp_max: 285.828,
pressure: 1019.23,
sea_level: 1029.02,
grnd_level: 1019.23,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 3.36,
deg: 98.0014
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-03 15:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486144800,
main: {
temp: 285.168,
temp_min: 285.168,
temp_max: 285.168,
pressure: 1018.15,
sea_level: 1027.96,
grnd_level: 1018.15,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 1.66,
deg: 333.002
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-03 18:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486155600,
main: {
temp: 283.818,
temp_min: 283.818,
temp_max: 283.818,
pressure: 1018.65,
sea_level: 1028.36,
grnd_level: 1018.65,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 3.77,
deg: 359.001
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-03 21:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486166400,
main: {
temp: 283.157,
temp_min: 283.157,
temp_max: 283.157,
pressure: 1019.84,
sea_level: 1029.41,
grnd_level: 1019.84,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 2.91,
deg: 18.5013
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-04 00:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486177200,
main: {
temp: 283.494,
temp_min: 283.494,
temp_max: 283.494,
pressure: 1018.56,
sea_level: 1028.13,
grnd_level: 1018.56,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 0.22,
deg: 280.501
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-04 03:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486188000,
main: {
temp: 285.263,
temp_min: 285.263,
temp_max: 285.263,
pressure: 1016.77,
sea_level: 1026.41,
grnd_level: 1016.77,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "clear sky",
icon: "01d"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 0
},
wind: {
speed: 1.88,
deg: 273.501
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "d"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-04 06:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486198800,
main: {
temp: 285.927,
temp_min: 285.927,
temp_max: 285.927,
pressure: 1017.03,
sea_level: 1026.52,
grnd_level: 1017.03,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 801,
main: "Clouds",
description: "few clouds",
icon: "02n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 12
},
wind: {
speed: 3.02,
deg: 269.505
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-04 09:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486209600,
main: {
temp: 285.906,
temp_min: 285.906,
temp_max: 285.906,
pressure: 1016.93,
sea_level: 1026.64,
grnd_level: 1016.93,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 802,
main: "Clouds",
description: "scattered clouds",
icon: "03n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 44
},
wind: {
speed: 3.77,
deg: 261.501
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-04 12:00:00"
},
{
dt: 1486220400,
main: {
temp: 285.51,
temp_min: 285.51,
temp_max: 285.51,
pressure: 1016.46,
sea_level: 1026.16,
grnd_level: 1016.46,
humidity: 100,
temp_kf: 0
},
weather: [
{
id: 802,
main: "Clouds",
description: "scattered clouds",
icon: "03n"
}
],
clouds: {
all: 44
},
wind: {
speed: 2.97,
deg: 283.001
},
rain: { },
sys: {
pod: "n"
},
dt_txt: "2017-02-04 15:00:00"
}
],
city: {
id: 1907296,
name: "Tawarano",
coord: {
lat: 35.0164,
lon: 139.0077
},
country: "none"
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `obj.forEach`, you need to use `map` in order to return the result since `forEach` doesn't return anything

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CurrentLocation extends Component {
  loopThroughKeys(obj) {
    return obj.map(function(obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).map(function() {
        let main = obj.main;
        return Object.keys(main).map(function(key) {
          let type = key;
          let value = main[key];
          console.log(type, value);
          return (
            <li>
              <span key={key}>
                {type}:{value}
              </span>
            </li>
          );
        });
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    let weather = this.props.weather;
    console.log(this.props.weather);
    if (!weather.list) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="currentWeather">
        <h1>hi</h1>
        <div className="container">
          <ul className="card">{this.loopThroughKeys(weather.list)}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CurrentLocation;
```

Comment: thanks heaps for that mate.

ended up changing it a little so its not as overly complicated. 

loopThroughKeys(obj, key) {
    return obj.map(function(val) {
      let value = val[key];
      return Object.keys(value).map(function(key) {
        return (
          <li>
            <span key={key}>
              {key}:{value[key]}
            </span>
          </li>
        );
      });
    });
  }

Comment: @benjoyce, instead of updating the question with the approach that solved the problem, consider accepting the answer that helped your reach the solution. I rolled back your edit, so that the question is useful for future readers